# Web Safe AND CMYK (U.S. Web Coated v2) swatch

Tags: color, print-design, color-profile, color-spaces, web-safe

I was curious if there such a thing exists such as a swatch of the intersection set of web-safe and cmyk compliant colors? Is there an adobe swatch library for this? My reasoning being to limit myself to design with only web, print and rgb safe colors.

Comment: Most CMYK colors are web-safe, except for maybe clean cyan. Have a look at [this simplified comparison between CMYK and RGB](https://artofmeganlorraine.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/gamut-rgb-cmyk.jpg)

Comment: All CMYK colours are within the gamut of RGB colours. The whole idea of "web-safe" colours is obsolete today, since it was conceived before web browsers and computers could display the full range of RGB colours.

Comment: both @Wolff and Billy thanks a lot. So a follow-up question which led me to ask the question above. When I'm in illustrator... I open a document in cmyk color space and pull up the web-safe swatch library, it actually pops up the out of web color warning (the box shaped icon below the color tab. What's the reason for this? Illustrator not having been updated?

Comment: I just tested it and it doesn't happen for me exactly like that in a *CMYK* document. Some of the "web-safe" colors gives me the "Out of Gamut Warning" because they can't be printed with CMYK. If you click the "!" triangle the color is adjusted so it's inside CMYK gamut, and then of course it's no longer "web-safe" because you changed it. Illustrator isn't outdated, it just still supports the legacy concept of "web-safe colors".

Comment: It's telling you that some RGB colours are out of gamut for CMYK printing. That's completely normal.  All CMYK colours are within the RGB gamut, but not vice versa.